Wrapping a UIKit view with initializer that can throw inside a SwiftUI screen
I'd like to know if there is a good existing way to wrap a UIKit inside SwiftUI when the initializer of the UIKit component can throw an error.
As a context, I'm using this article to create a generic wrapper like this:
struct Wrap<Wrapped: UIView>: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias Updater = (Wrapped, Context) -> Void

    var makeView: () -> Wrapped
    var update: (Wrapped, Context) -> Void

    init(_ makeView: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Wrapped,
         updater update: @escaping Updater) {
        self.makeView = makeView
        self.update = update
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> Wrapped {
        makeView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: Wrapped, context: Context) {
        update(view, context)
    }
}

extension Wrap {
    init(_ makeView: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Wrapped,
         updater update: @escaping (Wrapped) -> Void) {
        self.makeView = makeView
        self.update = { view, _ in update(view) }
    }

    init(_ makeView: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Wrapped) {
        self.makeView = makeView
        self.update = { _, _ in }
    }
}

Now, the problem is that, if the UIKit class has an initializer that can throw an error, attempting to use it in a SwiftUI screen will not compile:
final class MyView: UIView {

    init(text: String) throws {
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: 20)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


My understanding is that SwiftUI can’t handle this kind of situation normally, so what would be the best way to handle this kind of situation in a "SwiftUI" way?

Stuff in the body shouldn’t be “throwing” the body is for displaying things not doing things.

@loremipsum I understand, so what would you do if the component you want to use can throw?

"My understanding is that SwiftUI can’t handle this kind of situation" It isn't SwiftUI that has a problem here, so much as your Wrap struct.

Change the component, views aren’t supposed to throw, there isn’t a good separation of concerns if views are throwing.

Throwing SwiftUI views are not supported.
The question is, what is supposed to happen if the initializer throws an error?
If you want to show an empty view if the initializer fails, you could just return EmptyView.
func getMyViewWrapped() -> some View {
    do {
        let myView = try MyView(text: "test")
        return AnyView(Wrap(myView))
    } catch {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}

// use in View
self.getMyViewWrapped() // not throwing.

(Wrapped in AnyView to avoid the return type mismatch error)
Or if you want a one-liner for your view:
Wrap((try? MyView(text: "test")) ?? EmptyView())

should work as well (perhaps you also have to wrap it in AnyView though).

Unfortunately this one liner doesn't work because the type of EmptyView would be different from MyView, so the compiler complains that it cannot be casted.

@DielsonSales you can add ViewBuilder and remove the return to this function and it should work but it is a bad idea.
